# Building .ear and .war with maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3

I am generating a maven archetype using the following command "mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.core -DartifactId=myproject-core -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false", which generates the war file, now I want to build it using ear file.

I have gone through the web and some posts here that two different archetypes need to created for ear and war files. But I am not getting the starting point here.

Do I need the same archetype command which I am using to generate the structure or do I need to change the parameters? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [correct archetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-j2ee-simple](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List) instead of webapp cause EAR means Java EE application which usually contains at least two modules like:

```
 +-- root(pom.xml)
       +-- module-war (pom.xml)
       +-- module-ear (pom.xml)
```

Comment: I have formed that structure, now I want the APP-INF folder packaged in my .ear file , how can I achieve that?

Comment: Where is the APP-INF folder located ?

Comment: I got it, I am creating the APP-INF/lib folder through jarModule, I am inserting the required jar in the required directory,Thank you for the help guys